# grouping in big data without index

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am having a table which have many columns 
i want to do group by on 1 column to get the count of unique records
it is having data around 6 crores

i m using query as

```
select distinct lower(TITLE) , count(lower(TITLE)) as CountOf
from table_name2 
where 
((LENGTH(lower(TITLE)) - LENGTH(replace(lower(TITLE), ' ', '')))+1) > 3
HAVING COUNT(lower(TITLE))>1
group by lower(TITLE)
```

How can i do this in a efficient way such that if Title is "the rock garden area" and it is present in TITLE field 4 times then i get its countof -> 4

Comment: just remove `distinct` and that's it I think

Comment: also move `HAVING COUNT(lower(TITLE))>1` last, after group by

Comment: mysql or oracle? also, you have some redundant lower (count(a) = count(lower(a)), length(a) = length(lower(a)) )

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select 
 lower(TITLE) , 
 count(lower(TITLE)) as CountOf
from table_name2 
where 
REGEXP_COUNT ('asdaasd  ', '\s')+1 > 3
HAVING COUNT(TITLE)>1
group by TITLE
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
select  TITLE , count(TITLE) as CountOf
from (
    select LOWER(title) title
    from table_name2) t
where TITLE like '% % % %' 
group by TITLE
HAVING COUNT(TITLE)>1
```